# If I have applied a fixed window, will I always get an IntervalWindow from `window()`

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

If I implement a DoFn with access to the window, with the sidecondition that PCollection being transformed has already had some non-global windowing strategy applied to it, i.e. `FixedWidows` am I guaranteed to get an `IntervalWindow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The `window()` method returns whatever kind of window the current `WindowFn` has placed the element into. So, with `FixedWindows` this will always return an `IntervalWindow`.

It will also always return a single window. So if you're using `SlidingWindows` and each element is placed into 5 different windows, then the `processElement()` of a `DoFn` annotated with `RequiresWindowAccess` will be called once for each window the element is placed into (so 5 times for each element).

Comment: Good to know! I am guessing by your activity that you work on the dataflow platform, is there any chance of adding a method to Bounded window that includes the exclusive upper bound? It would be nice to not have to mangle the return value of `maxTimestamp` to get it (If you think there is a chance I will make an issue on github).

Comment: What are you looking to do? We could look at adding an exclusive upper bound method, but there are other options too. Would it be more helpful for all `BoundedWindow`s to be able to return some kind of "representative" timestamp (for use in filenames, etc.)? What using `toString()` to get the description of the window?

Comment: Yes. Essentially based on the window that the processed element was in I want to send the data to a particular row key (think bigtable / cassandra). Ideally I would like the inclusive start rather than the exclusive end, but either would work for my purposes. So "informative timestamp" seems like a good way to put it.

Comment: In general, a BoundedWindow doesn't have a start time. We only require that the they have an ending. If you know it's an IntervalWindow you could cast it which would let you get the start time out for now. We'll take a look at making something more informative available. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

For `FixedWindows`, yes. In general, no. The only general guarantee is that you'll get a `BoundedWindow`. Currently, all of the non-global windows provided by the SDK (`FixedWindows`, `SlidingWindows`, `Sessions`) use `IntervalWindow`s. But it's perfectly legal to have a non-global windowing strategy that uses only `BoundedWindow`s.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Unfortunately I lack the rep to upvote your answer.